# How to test OpenIm (ForgeRock) Request on Postman?

Tags: postman, openidm, forgerock

I have openIdm ForgeRock installed locally and I'am trying to go through the API Explorer etc. in order to see how to use the endpoints and the available endpoints.

From `localhost:8080` where ForgeRock is running I can run/try a request. It works fine and I see the Response with `Status 200` and its details.

When I try same Request URL on Postman, I get:

`{
    "code": 401,
    "reason": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Access Denied"
}`

In a way this makes sense for me as I'am not logged in in this case as directly via ForgeRock Server on `localhost:8080`. So how can I work around this to be able to run my tests also on Postman.

I tried the parameters `username=xxx` and `password=xxx` to the Request on Postman, but it keeps throwing the same error.

I also tried it on Postman as CURL request exactly how ForgeRock is using it, but it seems to have an issue with Authorization.

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'X-Requested-With: Swagger-UI' 'http://localhost:8080/openidm/managed/user?_queryId=query-all'
```

Any Idea please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. Was actually simple... Had to add the following in the headers:

```
X-OpenIDM-Username
X-OpenIDM-Password
```

Value is by default: `opendidm-admin` for both.